# Xamarin Forms After Adding Xam.Plugin.Connectivity GooglePlayconsole raise warning on signing APK user features

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, google-play

I faced a issue of warning as I went on publishing new release to test the Connectivity introduced.

I installed Xam.Plugin.Connectivity from NuGet Packages

```
using Plugin.Connectivity;
```

Created a function at Public class Level

```
    public static bool CheckConnection()
    {
        if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

And then called in my MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (Sql_Common.CheckConnection() == false)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Network Error!", "Network connection could not be establised to server!", "ok");
        }

    }
    protected void OnAppearingAsync()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        if (Sql_Common.CheckConnection() == false)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Network Error!", "Network connection could not be establised to server!", "ok");
        }
    }
```

But then the warning came at Publishing the APK as follows:

**Warning:
Deactivation of this APK will result in your app being available for new installs on fewer types of devices.
Tip:
If this is an unintended change, then retain this APK in the new release or ensure that your new APKs support all currently supported devices.**

**1 differentiating: android.hardware.wifi**

I did some google but could not reach the risk factor I was assuming that users may not get later updates or installations less on devices, due to adding this android.hardware.wifi feature requried.

So Please help me that can I proceed with this feature? Will it have any impact on my later releases? And am I correct that due to installing the Xam.Plugin.Connectivity, this warning has especially came?

Edited:-
One thing common was found
Adding following line into manifest file

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" required="false" />
```

was common suggestion but then will it still check the connectivity?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct that the warning comes because of adding the Xam.Plugin.Connectivity package to your project.

> The ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE and ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permissions are
>   required and are automatically added to your Android Manifest when you
>   compile. No need to add them manually!
>
> By adding these permissions Google Play will automatically filter out
>   devices without specific hardware.

You can get around this filtering by adding the following to your AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.wifi", Required = false)]
```

Source: [here](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/ConnectivityPlugin/GettingStarted.html)

Comment: @Raiomo : True. I missed that adding into my Question that there was option of adding following into manifest file <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" required="false" /> will still check the connectivity? I have edited my Question also! Thank you for reminding the exact point

Comment: @YeshwantMudholkar Yes, it will still function as normal. It is simply a workaround to avoid Google Play from filtering out devices as you can read in the quote or the source I linked. I edited my answer.